# Building an enterprise CRUD application with WPF and EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, prism

I am building a WPF CRUD application, most of the application functionality is centered around DB operations, and i find my self doing the same thing over and over again. define a view with input fields, then go for the view model, then implement the validation, exception handling, repositry, etc. but the most daunting and time wasting operation is building the user interface along with its view model. What's your best advise or experience to speed up development of such applications, any suggested tools, frameworks, controls, etc ?!
**NOTE:** I like the ideas of domain driven development and code first approach so i would love that the solutions to cope with those, and my main interest is in Desktop WPF apps.

Comment: Have you considered LightSwitch? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff796201.aspx

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, Thanks a lot, it seems exactly what i want, but i need to know if it works well with WPF, code-first and domain-driven development mentality as i have updated my question to show that ?. don't want to go through all the tutorials to find the answer.

Comment: From what I understand, most of the business logic is server-side via WCF (or maybe ASP.NET) and the GUI is more (or completely) data-driven rather than by code/XAML. The users interact either via thin-client in-browser Silverlight, on-desktop Silverlight out-of-browser, or in-browser auto-generated HTML5/JS (this is upcoming and in "preview" phase right now). You can build your own custom controls/components from scratch, but I'm not sure to what level of control you have to deviate from the LightSwitch development workflow. Silverlight development however is very close to WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will quickly run into crippling limitations and dead ends when using Scaffolding or LightSwitch. In the long run it's probably better to build a well organised WPF application using MVVM.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because i have gone this route and found out that your totally correct, plus light switch only works as a 3-tier application while my quest is layered architecture with local db access.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29).

Here's a tutorial about [WPF Scaffolding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding).

Comment: it seems to do the job too along with its integration with my needs. but i want accept the answer until i see what light switch is capable of.